# Flutter pub get failed many times

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, cross-platform

I tried "flutter pub get" and this was the message :

```
Because flash_chat depends on flutter any from sdk which doesn't exist (unknown SDK "flutterx"), version solving failed.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
```

note: flutter doctor works has no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `pubspec.yaml`.  The `flutter` dependency should look like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

If you accidentally change this to `sdk: flutterx`, you get the error message you reported.

Comment: `dependencies:

  flutter:

    sdk: flutterx

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  animated_text_kit: ^2.2.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.0`

Comment: It should be `sdk: flutter`, not `sdk: flutterx`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your internet connection once.

Comment: Cool! Have a look at answers here... 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52223